# Installed mysql in ubuntu docker container, error on checking mysql version

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu, apt, docker-container

I input these commands on linux machine with docker installed:
(this approach is not what most people choose to run mysql in docker)

```
docker container run -it -d --restart always -p 4100:80 --name myapp ubuntu:22.04
docker exec -it --user=root myapp /bin/bash
apt update
apt install mysql-server
apt install mysql-client
mysql -v
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

What do I need to do to fix or run mysql inside a ubuntu(or any distro) container, so any script(php/python) inside same ubuntu container can connect to mysql database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A Docker container usually only runs one process; correspondingly, it's unusual for that process to be an interactive shell or to run the unmodified `ubuntu` image.  A much more common setup for the sort of application you describe is to run a dedicated MySQL container next to your application container, maybe using Docker Compose to launch both containers together.  The Docker documentation has a [Django sample application](https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/) that illustrates this.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the info, I was avoiding multiple "multiple container apps" because with that type of setup I think maybe all containers will look like mixed when listed in terminal and will take some time to understand which containers are for which app. Small things: I may also have to keep mysql networking port open to connect app to db, & maybe accidently db of App1 can connect to another App2. | Another option VM is heavy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to put the password and the root user when you are running the container
for example  :
`docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag`

anyways with the following link I could use MySQL image and make a container from it I hope that you will find this answer useful

[docker-my-sql-reference](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)